# Can't send outgoing MESSAGE sip request

Tags: java, sip, mobicents-sip-servlets

I'm trying to send an outgoing sip request to another server but the request is just routing back to my server. I need to send the request via UDP. I'm using MOBICENTS Sip Servlets.

Here's the logs:

> 2013-05-20 23:30:35,175 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] 
>   (SelfRoutingThread-19) 
>  
>   from="10.214.77.65:5060" 
>   to="10.214.77.65:5060" 
>   time="0" 
>   isSender="false" 
>   transactionId="z9hg4bk1a739dca-0982-4c19-91c2-d6b30cde0e44_8017d156_6924298232771001" 
>   callId="cec3692d7ee2e3771d3b2ecbd5408cf5@10.214.77.65" 
>   firstLine="MESSAGE sip:1404xxxxxxx@sms-proxy-01.bandwidthclec.com:5060 SIP/2.0" 
>   
>   `` <![CDATA[MESSAGE sip:1404xxxxxxx@sms-proxy-01.bandwidthclec.com:5060 SIP/2.0` 
>
>   Call-ID: cec3692d7ee2e3771d3b2ecbd5408cf5@10.214.77.65 
>
>   CSeq: 1 MESSAGE 
>
>   From:`<sip:1404xxxxxxx@216.27.87.216>`;tag=32496860_8017d156_1a739dca-0982-4c19-91c2- d6b30cde0e44 
>
>   To:`<sip:63917xxxxxxx@216.27.87.216>` 
>
>   Max-Forwards: 70 
>
>   Content-Type: text/plain 
>
>   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 23.21.213.9:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1a739dca-0982-4c19-91c2- 
>  d6b30cde0e44_8017d156_6924298232771001 
>
>   Route: 
>  pid=1a739dca-0982-4c19-91c2-d6b30cde0e44> 
>
>   Content-Length: 7 
>
>   
>
>   foo-bar]]> ``

Here's my DAR config:

> ALL:("RestComm", "DAR:From", "NEUTRAL", "", "NO_ROUTE", "0") 
>   INVITE:("org.mobicents.servlet.sip.example.CallBlockingApplication", "DAR:From", "ORIGINATING", "", "NO_ROUTE", "0") 
>   REGISTER:("RestComm", "DAR:From", "NEUTRAL", "", "NO_ROUTE", "0") 
>   MESSAGE:("SmsReceiver", "DAR:TO", "ORIGINATING", "", "NO_ROUTE", "0", "DIRECTION=OUTBOUND")

Here's my code (using HttpServlet) that sends the message:

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            SipFactory sf = (SipFactory) getServletContext().getAttribute(
                            "javax.servlet.sip.SipFactory");

            SipApplicationSession appSession = ((ConvergedHttpSession) request
                            .getSession()).getApplicationSession();

            logger.info("sipfactory= " + sf);
            logger.info("appSession=" + appSession);

            try {
                    SipServletRequest sipRequest = sf.createRequest(appSession, "MESSAGE","sip:1404xxxxxxx8@216.27.87.216",
                                    "sip:63917xxxxxxx@216.27.87.216");


                   //the uri where I want to send my message
                    SipURI uri = sf.createSipURI("1404xxxxxxx", "sms-proxy-01.bandwidthclec.com");
                    uri.setPort(5060);                                                

                    sipRequest.setRequestURI(uri);


                   //message content
                    sipRequest.setContent("foo-bar", "text/plain");
                    logger.info("sipRequest= " + sipRequest);
                    sipRequest.send();
            } catch (ServletParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

any help/advice would be great.

thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked the logs on the server you're sending the request to? what is that in the logs: (SelfRoutingThread-19)
from="10.214.77.65:5060"
to="10.214.77.65:5060"

Comment: seems From and To are the same! Also is this IP 23.21.213.9:5060 on the same machine (different Ethernet) as 10.214.77.65:5060

Comment: @hovanessyan Yes you're right 10.214.77.65 and 23.21.213.9 is just the same which is the IP of my web server. The question is when I'm sending a sip request it's just returning back to my web server (to and from is the same). I can't really see the logs of the server I want to send the request to. I think If I had successfully sent the message to that server I should get a response right?

Comment: Yes, that's true - you should get a response. But don't you think you should have the "To" header pointing to the destination server? Or are you also running a sip-relay on the same ip 10.214.77.65?

Comment: I recommend that you test the connection to the SIP Server using a third party client software (I've been using Ekiga, but there's tons of others) - just to check that the server responses are OK. If this is a success - that means your SIP message is not crafted correctly.

Comment: @hovanessyan That's what I'm confused about: on why is the "To" header not pointing to the destination server. As you can see in the code: 

SipURI uri = sf.createSipURI("1404xxxxxxx", "sms-proxy-01.bandwidthclec.com");
uri.setPort(5060);                                                
sipRequest.setRequestURI(uri);

Comment: I've pointed the request uri by calling the setRequestURI of the sipRequest I created. But I don't know why the 'To' header is still pointing on my server

Comment: You should put the destination address in the "createRequest" method. From the docs "createRequest - Returns a new request object with the specified request method, From, and To headers."

Comment: Yup, I already did that. You can see that in my code. I still don't know what to do. Does the dar config matters for this issue?

Comment: Yes DAR matters. If you just intend to use for sending outgoing messages, remove all DAR information leave it blank and this should work. More information on DAR available at https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Mobicents-SipServlets-Release/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/documentation/html_single/index.html#tsdar-Default-Application-Router